# Highlight search text after , in Li

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use `,` in search input then `,` and text after comma is not getting selected. This is because I am using `.split` method. I have data in below format. I have to display first line in strong tag. so that I have split it out using `,` separator.

```
<li><strong>my name is amit</strong>, address</li>
<li><strong>my name is geeta</strong>, address</li>
<li><strong>my name is xyz</strong>, address</li>


$(this).html(function(val,html){                    
return "<strong>"+txt.split(',')[0]+"</strong>," + txt.split(',')[1]
});
```

My `.replace` method is working fine. The following code giving value like

```
txt = txt.replace(nn, "<span class='highlight'>" + '$1' + "</span>");
```

if I type "My name is amit, add" then output reproduced by code is

```
<span class='highlight'>My name is amit, add</span>ress
```

I know the problem but how to fix it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumL5eas/)

Comment: type "my name is amit, add" in search box, you will see the prblem

Comment: That is because you split on `,`

Comment: I see the "problem", but what is *supposed* to happen?

Comment: @RGraham: the search text should be selected even after , and text after , should not be in bold format

Comment: Check in typed text for "," and split it too. Then use it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split out it again as @Alexander Ravikovich suggested and its finally work for me. here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumL5eas/18/)

```
 if ($('.highlight', this).text().indexOf(',') != -1) {
    var x = $('.highlight', this).text().split(',');
    $(this).html("<strong><span class='highlight'>" + x[0] + "</span></strong><span class='highlight'>," + x[1] + "</span>" + $.trim($(this).text()).substr(val.length, $.trim($(this)).length))
} else {
    $(this).html(function() {
        return "<strong>" + txt.split(',')[0] + "</strong>," + txt.split(',')[1];
    });
}
```

```js
$('.inp').keyup(function(){
        var val=this.value          
        $('ul li').each(function(){
          var e = '(^| )' + val;           
           var l = $(this).text() 
            var a = new RegExp(e, "i");            
            if(!a.test(l)){
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else{
                $(this).show();                
            var reg = new RegExp('\\b(' + val + ')', 'gi'),            
            txt = $(this).text();                            
             if (val.replace(/\s/g, '') == '') {
                txt = txt.replace(new RegExp("<span class='highlight'>([\s\S]*?)</span>"),'$1');
                $(this).html(function(){
                    return "<strong>"+txt.split(',')[0]+"</strong>,"+ txt.split(',')[1]
                });
            }
            else{
            txt = txt.replace(reg, "<span class='highlight'>" + '$1' + "</span>");            
                $(this).html(txt);
                if($('.highlight',this).text().indexOf(',')!=-1){
                    var x=$('.highlight',this).text().split(',');                
                $(this).html("<strong><span class='highlight'>"+x[0]+"</span></strong><span class='highlight'>,"+x[1]+"</span>"+$.trim($(this).text()).substr(val.length,$.trim($(this)).length))
                }
                else{
                    $(this).html(function(){
                        return "<strong>"+txt.split(',')[0]+"</strong>," + txt.split(',')[1];
                    });
                }
            }

            }
        })
    })
```

```css
.highlight{color:#ff0000}

input{width:300px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inp" />

<ul>
<li><strong>my name is amit</strong>, address</li>
<li><strong>my name is geeta</strong>, address</li>
<li><strong>my name is xyz</strong>, address</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a quirk with span, .html() moves the closing span tag inside the closing strong tag, since it was opened inside the strong tag.

If you change it to use div with display: inline-block, as seen in **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumL5eas/6/)**, it works.

```
txt = txt.replace(nn, "<div class='highlight'>" + '$1' + "</div>");
```

which produces a result like

[image: Partial highlight]

Where the text after "," is not bold, but all the matched text is highlighted.

Comment: html reproduced by code is not correct. <strong><div class='highlight'>my name is amit</strong>, address</div>

Comment: Why is that not correct? You want address to get highlighted, and the text after , should not be in bold format. According to your  comments on the original post.

Comment: but the closing tag is not right place in html. which may create problem on other browsers

Comment: The closing tag is at the end of the matched result, is that not the desired html? I search for "my name is amit, add" and get the html "<div class="highlight"><strong>my name is amit</strong>, add</div>ress".

Comment: apart from code. your code is working fine but when you type space its remove the space from two word