# Filter data in table view

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

Speed up search function.

I have data in table format. every row contains somewhere around 5 to 6 row and it cab increased as per requirement. I have made small function for search and highlight the search text in table which is working fine with small data. But it is taking time with very large data like 800 ,2000, 5000 rows. So how can I speed up my function.

I am also considering plugin if there any. I google it but did no find.

here is example code in accepted answer
[Highlight search text after , in Li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649224/highlight-search-text-after-in-li)

and table data view example is 
[image]

Comment: Can you add your code example of what you have tried?

Comment: Sounds like you may have a much bigger problem than finding how to highlight the text. If you have a table with "very large data like 800 ,2000, 5000 rows", that is going to make navigating the page to find highlighted text a nightmare. Filtering the table with only relevant results in a better solution, like this example: http://codepen.io/PageOnline/pen/nCfAj

Comment: @BenRondeau: is codepen examle in angular js?

Comment: Yes - it is just an example to communicate filtering data. It is not an endorsement or recommendation to use Angular, just a better way to search a table of data to find what you are looking for (especially if it is a thousand+ rows)